# Android - How to allow items behind alertdialog to be clicked?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have created an alert dialog. I need a functionality by which items behind alert dialog can be clicked.

Currently, when we click outside alert dialog the alert dialog dismisses. However, I want the alert dialog to dismiss and view behind it is also clicked when we click outside the alert dialog.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you want an AlertDialog then?

Answer (score 0):

How about wrap all the code in the button click listener in a method and call that method instead when you dismiss the alertdialog